# Extend angularjs $resource service to include common headers

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I want to write a wrapper service to the existing angular [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) service such that some custom headers are added to the http request by default. I am aware that we can set common headers using `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common`. But this way all my requests would have this header and that is not what I want.

It would be lot more cleaner if the `$resource` service could be extended into a wrapper service in which I can define these common headers. This way I could selectively use this wrapper service wherever the common headers need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for but I will share my thoughts. I'm using angular $http. The way I do it is I specify the correct header in every api call.

Something like this:

```
authenticatePlayer: function(postData) {
        return $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : api + 'auth/player',
          data    : postData,
          headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
        });
      },

uploadAvatar: function(email_address, fd) {
        return $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : api + 'player/' + email_address + '/avatar',
          data    : fd,
          withCredentials: true,
          headers : {'Content-Type' : undefined, 'X-Token' : credential.token},
          transformRequest: angular.identity //awesome! automatically set to the correct header request
        });
      },
fbLogin: function(data) {
        var xsrf = $.param({fb_access_token: data});
        // console.log(postData);
        return $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : api + '/user/v1/login',
          data    : xsrf,
          headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        });
      }
```

I'm not an expert in angular but this is the way I do it. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't solve my problem. Also you should be using $resource service rather than $http service.